# How can you join int and list together?

Tags: python, tail-recursion

But I still can't find the join function anywhere else on the internet. The main problem is that the head(items) is int and tail(items) is list, and I can't combine head and tail together. Here is the code I tried:

```
def head(items):  
    return items[0]  
def tail(items):
    return items[1:]  
def isEven(x):  
     return x % 2 == 0  
def extractEvens(items):  
    if (items == None):  
        return None  
    elif (isEven(head(items))):  
        return join(head(items),extractEvens(tail(items)))  
    else:  
        return extractEvens(tail(items)) 



a = [4,2,5,2,7,0,8,3,7]  
print(extractEvens(a))
```

Here is the link for the page I tried to study: The is the code for filter pattern:
[link_of_code](http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/book/index_17.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Hint 1: you can add two lists together using `+`. Hint 2: You can create a list containing a single integer using `[some_number]`.

Comment: ', '.join(tail(items))

Comment: It looks like a LISP programmer trying to python...

Comment: Well I do know that, but if I make head(items) a list with 1 int, then the even command wouldn't work.

Comment: I want to concanated list of 1 item which is head and repeat itself with the rest of the list. I tried to learn tail-recursion. Otherwise I would do for loop. The desired output is a list with extracted even numbers from the input list. For example, 
    y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
    extractEvens(y) 
    >>>[2,4,6]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `insert` which is even more useful as the head must be in the starting.

```
l = extractEvens(tail(items))
l.insert(0,head(items))
return l
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide an example of the desired output.

If you want to create a new `list`, merging a list with an `int`, it should be:

```py
return [head(items)] + tail(items)
```

Comment: the desired output is a list with extracted even numbers from the input list. For example, 
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
extractEvens(y)
>>>[2,4,6]

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `append`

```
>>> a=6
>>> b=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

here you just cant concanate list and int:

```
>>> a=6
>>> b=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
>>> list(a)+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

but if you do `str`, it will concanated as `str` not `int`:

```
>>> list(str(a))+b
['6', 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I want to concanated list of 1 item which is head and repeat itself with the rest of the list. I tried to learn tail-recursion. Otherwise I would do for loop. The desired output is a list with extracted even numbers from the input list. For example, 
    y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
    extractEvens(y) 
    >>>[2,4,6]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code:

```
def isEven(x):
    return x % 2 == 0 # x % 2 not x % ==


def extractEvens(items):
    if not items:
        return [] # return empty list not None
    elif isEven(head(items)):
         # convert ints to strings and put head(items) in a list 
        return "".join(map(str,[head(items)]) + map(str,extractEvens(tail(items)))) 
    else:
        return extractEvens(tail(items))
```

You can also do this in a single list comprehension:

```
a = [4, 2, 5, 2, 7, 0, 8, 3, 7]
print("".join([str(x) for x in a if not x % 2]))
```